# How do a I modify the key in an associative array, hash, or dictionary in swagger for documentation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm looking to document a json object in Swagger (using Swashbuckle, .net core), and I'd like to find a way to mention that the key of the object should have some meaning.  In my example below, the key is a string of a collection name, and the value is the content of that collection.

Is there a way to do this?  I can easily put in examples, that's no issue, but something to modify the model would helpful.

[image: Swagger Sample]